# how do I change the default icon size of smooth tasks plasma taskbar?

Tags: kde, taskbar

By default the icons are completely square, so while I can make them wider, that has the effect of making them taller. I want to perfectly emulate the windows 7 taskbar, but changing the space between the buttons doesn't have the effect I want. I know it is capable of changing their width, the "grow at attention" (pun not intended) is proof of that, I just want to know how I can make it about 2/3 as tall as it is wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using the "minimal icon space" parameter in the settings menu of the widget allows me to change the contracted/non-expanded button width by pixel dimension

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'm the asker, I found the answer myself after no one left one for over 2-3 days

Comment: @sbergeron - yes, but you can still add more information to make this more helpful for those that find this post later.

Comment: I think that's about as expanded out as I can get